# Why does my Vue component ignore media queries?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, responsive-design

I have this code snippet that is ignored in the scoped style of a Vue component.

```
        nav {
            background: none;
            box-shadow: none;

            .sidenav-trigger {
                background: none;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;

                i {
                    color: #f8f9fa;
                    font-size: 36px;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        nav {
            background: #f8f9fa;

            .sidenav-trigger {
                i {
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried to use min-width and other css specificity stuff, but unfortunately, none of them worked. Moreover, I used different browsers for further exploration, but it did not have anything to with the problem. Also, I haven't forgotten to put viewport tag in index.html file. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The braces are not balanced for a start.

Comment: I guess you have the `scoped` attribute on the parent's style and you want to apply style on a children, right? the `scoped` attributes adds a data attribute to the selectors so it's `scoped` only for a given component, you can remove the `scoped` attribute or add the children mediaquery on the children's style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have one more selector above like:`section nav`
and in de media query only `nav`.
than the first expression is higher level .)

Comment: thanks, it worked as a charm. Yes, sass specificity stuff.